# Powershell here-string expansion

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**Here-strings**

There are some examples regarding Powershell 'here-string' but I have hardly come across 'here-string' expansion. so I posted this to be of some help.
When you want to add some literal with line breaks, both single and double quotes do not need to be escaped and no need for line breaks like `` "`r`n" ``. 'here-strings' comes to the rescue in PowerShell. 
They should start with

@"
   and line break and should end with line break 
  "@

```
For example:                        |Result:
                                    |
@"                                  |
Hello world! 09/25/2014 11:39:56    |      Hello world! 09/25/2014 11:39:56
'(this will appear as is)'          |      '(this will appear as is)'
!                                   |      !
"@                                  |
```

Comment: I would eliminate your first example as it is somewhat misleading - the closing `"@` has to appear on a new line staring in column 0.  Also here strings can be both single quoted and double quoted.  Double quoted string support not only variable interpolation but sub-expressions as well e.g. `$((get-process -id $pid).MainWindowTitle)`.

Comment: @Keith I have edited the first example. I was looking for 'here-string' example specific to variable interpolation and didn't come across any after Googling. so I just posted specific solution. I think examples of other application of 'here-string' are plenty and easily found.

Comment: Before you take to Google, try looking in the PowerShell help.  :-)  Specifically `man about_Quoting_Rules`.

Comment: Now I look back and try to **man &%^%^%&^** but I still have to Google **man &^%*^&*^** first to find what I am about to **manning**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how to introduce CmdLet and a date variable to show current date like so:

For example the following is what we want to achieve:

```
Hello world! 09/25/2014 11:39:56
'(this will appear as is)'
!
```

Here is how:

```
@"
Hello world! $(Get-Date)
'(this will appear as is)'
!
"@
```

Or with variable:

```
$myDate = Get-Date
@"
Hello world! ${myDate}
'(this will appear as is)'
!
"@
```

Comment: Cool this is good to know. I fixed your here-string terminations as they were incorrect `@"` text `"@`. Its a pending edit. Else you would get this error `The string is missing the terminator: "@`

Answer (score 1):

This post is helpful and I landed here from looking for expanding a variable within a PowerShell here-string in a SQL query.

The following code snip will get a list of servers then loop in a `Foreach-Object` allowing the server name to be replaced for every query!

Thanks to @Matt for the [hash-table help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325577/4317867).

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\scripts\list.txt

$servers | ForEach-Object{
 $items = @{}
 $items.Server = $_

$query = @"
 WHERE svrName = $($items.Server)
"@
}
```