# Foreach loop output DateTime object plus other details.

Tags: powershell, datetime, foreach

I'm having trouble getting a Powershell `Foreach` loop to output a `[DateTime]` object so I can compare it with another object after rebooting.

Example script below, I'm looking to create a hashtable to store the Computername + Last reboot time then add a current reboot time so the reboot times can be compared.

```
$servers = GC D:\Scripts\list1.txt

foreach($server in $servers){

 Try{
  $operatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server
  $current = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)

  "$server last rebooted $current"
 }#end try

 Catch{
  $err = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
  Write-Warning "$err on $($server)"}#end catch

}#End foreach
```

-Edit, the above script outputs the below as a string.  I'm trying to get a collection of `TypeName: System.DateTime` objects.

```
Server1 last rebooted 10/24/2015 11:39:34
Server2 last rebooted 10/22/2015 01:34:33
```

So I poked around more and got this line, essentially the script becomes "Reboot the computers until everything is current."

```
IF($current -gt ((Get-Date).AddHours(-6)))
{"Server reboot is current for $server"}ELSE{"Please check $server"}
```

Comment: While I'm sure we can figure it out by testing it would be a lot easier if you showed us what was wrong and what you expect to see.

Comment: Ah great point, added examples.  Deadlines are closer than they appear in the mirror!

Comment: If you want to output the datetime object then dont wrap it in a string.

Comment: Of course, then I'll have dates and times with no server to reference.  The reason why I was trying to work out using a hashtable or PSCustomObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason why I was trying to work out using a hashtable or PSCustomObject.

Can't it be both!

```
$servers = Get-Content "D:\Scripts\list1.txt"

$servers | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{}
    $props.Server = $_
    Try{
        $operatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $props.Server
        $props.LastBootTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)
    } Catch {
      $err = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
      $props.LastBootTime = $null
      Write-Warning "$err on $($props.Server)"
    }#end catch

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
}#End foreach
```

Change the loop structure as it is easier for output to be piped if need be. Build a hashtable for each loop pass that is converted into an object after the try/catch block. Untested but it *should* work.